# wny popover not display in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using [this component](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) in my example, but when I click on my icon, my popover is not displayed.

When I click on an icon it should display the popover but currently, it is not display anything.

Here is my code (and [this](http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/RRVAry) is the CodePen):

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
  <div>hhh</div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, from my own experience I recommend using [angular-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for things in that scope.

Second, if you really want it to work, make sure the bootstrap scripts are correctly loaded. Then try to listen to the click event with ng-click on the button and trigger the popover on it.

Here is the code to achieve what you want.
Here is the plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/fBPJ8LfOFGlgcCHvRWSM?p=preview
Regards,

```
scope.popover = function() {
        $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
          html: true,
          content: $('.popper-content').html(),
          placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
        });
      };
```

Here is the html:

```
<button type="button" popover-placement="bottom" class="popper btn-link" popover ng-click="popover()" data-toggle="popover">
        4 Peoples
</button>
```

Regards,